# Computing Makefile variable on assignment

Tags: makefile

In a Makefile, I'm trying to assign the result of a shell command to a variable:

```
TMP=`mktemp -d /tmp/.XXXXX`

all:
    echo $(TMP)
    echo $(TMP)
```

but

```
$ make Makefile all
```

is echoing 2 different values, eg:

```
/tmp/.gLpm1T
/tmp/.aR4cDi
```

What is the syntax for mktemp to be computed on variable assignment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It depends on the flavour of make. With GNU Make, you can use `:=` instead of `=` as in

```
TMP:=$(shell mktemp -d /tmp/.XXXXX)
```

**Edit** As pointed out by Novelocrat, the `=` assignment differs from `:=` assignment in that values assigned using `=` will be evaluated during substitution (and thus, each time, the variable is used), whereas `:=` assigned variables will have their values evaluated only once (during assignment), and hence, the values are fixed after that. See the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors) of GNU Make for a more detailed explanation.

In order for the value to be truly constant after assignment, though, it should not contain any parts, which might be special to the shell (which `make` calls in order to actually run the update rules, etc.) In particular, backticks are best avoided. Instead, use GNU `make`'s built-in shell function and similar to achieve your goals.

Comment: Variables assigned with `=` are evaluated at each substitution. Variables assigned with `:=` are evaluated at assignment, as you desire.

Comment: Hi Dirk,
It does not seem to work: http://pastie.org/619606

Is there a syntax error in my Makefile?

Thanks

Comment: Edited answer again. I think, the problem is the use of the backticks; for make, the value (incl. the backticks) is essentially "constant" and will get pasted as is at the point of use -- and then, the backticks will be seen by the shell at each point of use. Just a theory, though.

Comment: Ok, finally found solution, thanks to you and your link:
I have to use := for assignment operator, but also $(shell mktemp -d /tmp/.XXXXX)

It works now, thank you so much!

Comment: I've accepted your answer, please add the $(shell <cmd>) tip ;)

Comment: While the code in this answer is correct, the explanation is incorrect. Using `:=` does not solve the problem. Using `$(shell ...)` does.

Answer (score 10):

If you’re using GNU Make, instead of using backticks, use `$(shell ...)`. For example,

```
TMP=$(shell mktemp -d /tmp/.XXXXX)
```