# Why don't environment variables work in $(shell) commands?

Tags: makefile

```
export HELLO=Hello,world
all:
        @echo $(HELLO)
        @echo $(shell echo $$HELLO)
        @echo `echo $$HELLO`
```

outputs:

```
Hello,world

Hello,world
```

Why is there a difference between backtick and $(shell), and is there a way to pass the environment variables to $(shell) invocations?

I'm trying to use pkg-config in a cross-compilation environment, so I need to set $PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT.  I can use backticks, but it's executed once for every .o file.  As per [Computing Makefile variable on assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435861/computing-makefile-variable-on-assignment), I need to use PKG_CFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config $(PACKAGES)), but I can't pass in the required environment variable to make that work properly.

Tested on GNU Make 4.0.

Comment: The backticks in the third line are unnecessary and don't change anything as compared to just using `@echo $$HELLO`.

Comment: Yes they do - the  point is to spawn a subshell.  It was more concise to explain it that way than SUBSHELL_HELLO=`echo $$HELLO`  then @echo $(SUBSHELL_HELLO)   There were backticks there, but comment formatting eats them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Congratulations you have hit a make bug: [$(shell) doesn't honor export but this is undocumented?](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=10593)

There's a comment in the code (that precede's the filing of the ticket and is quoted in the ticket) which indicates that there are complicated situations where this cannot work correctly and so it appears that it just isn't done.

I can think of two ways to get the `$(shell)` environment to have the variables you want to set manually available.

1. Set them in the `$(shell)` context explicitly.

   ```
   PCVAR:=$(shell PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT=$(make-level-variable-PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT) pkg-config ...)
   ```
2. Set them in the `make` processes environment so the `$(shell)` environment inherits them normally.

   ```
   $ PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT=/some/path make
   ```

Comment: Thank you, I was running in circles over this.  Is there a workaround aside from using backticks?  This bug combined with the mktemp issue in my referenced question would seem to make some kinds of evaluations entirely impossible.

Comment: Set the variable in the environment that runs make `PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT=/some/path make`?

Comment: Set it in the `$(shell)` environment manually? `PCVAR:=$(shell PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT=$(make-level-PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT) pkg-config ...)`?

Comment: Perfect, that does exactly what I want.  Perhaps edit that into your answer so it's easier to find?